# AvsP - Frame sizes don't match

Tags: video

This is potentially the wrong exchange for this, but here goes.

Trying to put scenes together in AvsP, and for some reason it isn't allowing me to splice, saying the frame size's don't match, even though I've used LanczosResize to ensure that all the scenes are 320x240.

Fired a bit below to look at.

```
Title screen clip
Title="C:...\Untitled.jpg"
TitleClip=ImageReader(Title, fps=25, end=74)
CroppedTitle=Crop(TitleClip,664-320,475-240,320,240)
TitleAndText=Subtitle(CroppedTitle,"Computer-supported Cooperative Work",
\160,120,1,size=17,text_color=color_crimson, align=5)
TitleAndText
LanczosResize(320, 240)

First scene of full matrix
Matrix="C:...\scene1.jpg"
MatrixClip=ImageReader(Matrix, end=149, fps=25)
MatrixClip
LanczosResize(320, 240)
```

And then when I try to put them togehter:

```
Opening=TitleAndText+MatrixClip
```

This line is throwing the error. What am I missing?